# mpandroidChart How to drawZeroline?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]
I drew a horizontal zero-line, but I can't draw a vertical zero-line. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
  xAxis.setAxisLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.binding.getRoot().getContext(), 
    R.color.white));
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setTextSize(9f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.binding.getRoot().getContext(), 
    R.color.white));

    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xVals));
    xAxis.setLabelCount(2);
    xAxis.mAxisMaximum = 2f;
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
    xAxis.setSpaceMin(1f);
    xAxis.setSpaceMax(1f);

    YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    leftAxis.setZeroLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.binding.getRoot().getContext(), R.color.white));
    leftAxis.setAxisLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.binding.getRoot().getContext(), R.color.white));
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(5f);
    leftAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(holder.binding.getRoot().getContext(), R.color.white));
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);
```